# How to inner join with not in or not exist in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have some data like this
for user

```
id | username | email
1  | test     | test@test.com
2  | om       | test2@test2.com
3  | aa       | test3@test3.com
```

And I have data user biodata like this

```
id | username | bio
1  | test     | test
2  | om       | test2
```

So, I want use not in with inner join for showing data with `where user.username not in biodata.username` and I try like this but it's error

```
select user.*, biodata.* from user inner join biodata on user.username = biodata.username where user.username not in biodata.username;
```

So, how to use that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This calls for the common `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`  pattern.

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email
  FROM user u
  LEFT JOIN biodata b ON u.username = b.username
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

The `LEFT JOIN` operation preserves all rows in `user`, whether or not they have matches in `biodata`. (By contrast, an ordinary `JOIN` would suppress rows from `user` that didn't have matches.) The `b.id IS NULL` operation filters out the rows that *do* have matches.

Answer (score 3):

She wants the names (user.username) that are not present in biodata table. Left Join preserves ALL records from table users and MATCHING records fom table biodata (good explanation in W3Schools [Left Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)). The where clause searches usernames that are not present in biodata:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email 
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN biodata bd 
ON u.username = bd.username 
WHERE u.username 
NOT IN (select username from biodata);
```

The correct output is:

```
id | username | email
3  |    aa    | test3@test3.com
```

I belive that you are trying to do an 'EXCEPT'. But some SGBDS like MySQL don't have this option.

[image: Except]